# ASP.NET Core migration to Core 3.0: Migration warning CS0618 'RazorViewAttribute' is obsolete

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, razor-pages, asp.net-core-3.0

After migration to Core 3.0 the error/warning list is full of

> 'RazorViewAttribute' is obsolete: 'This attribute has been superseded
>   by RazorCompiledItem and will not be used by the runtime.'

warnings are located in the generated files e.g. `..\obj\Debug\netcoreapp3.0\Razor\Areas\Auth\Pages\GroupEditPartial.cshtml.g.cs`

I have deleted all obj folder but this doesn't help.

New empty razor page application compiles wihtout warnings, but I can't find any differences between the code by myself.

Answer (score 12):

I had the same problem after upgrading to .NET core 3.0.
Removing the following references from my project solved the problem and made the warnings disappear.

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc (2.2.0)
- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.Design (2.2.0)

I hope this helps!

Comment: It didn't work for me. The warnings still are displaying

Comment: I had the same problem. This answer solved my problem.

Comment: Instead of this which one we need to use ?

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft has decided to switch from the Nuget Packages to a Framework Reference. All obsolete (Microsoft Packages with Version 2.2.0 or earlier) should be removed from the Project. This has to be done manually. See [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/22-to-30?view=aspnetcore-3.0&tabs=visual-studio#remove-obsolete-package-references) for a complete upgrade guide.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

After the migration I got dependencies list like this:

[image]

Old references should be deleted manually. Then warning gone.

But I can't udnerstand what kind of conflict we have there. Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc 2.2.0 is the latest version of the lib. How Microsoft.AspNetCore.App framework can conflict with the latest lib?